# Issues with search query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to run a search query on all of my comments. I am encountering a number of problems. I would to have two search queries one that runs a search on the comment ID and another that runs a search on the username that is connected to the comment through the user_id FK.

Currently im getting the problem:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in
```

Tables: 
Comment- id, comment, user_id, timestamps
User - id, name, username

Models:

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $comment =Comment::paginate(10);

    $id=$request->input('id');
    $name=$request->input('username');


    if(!empty($id)){
        $comment->where('id', $request->input('id') )->get();
    }
    if(!empty($name)){
        $comment->where($comment->author->username, 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }


    return view('comments.index')->withComment($comment);
}
```

View:

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'comments.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {!! Form::label('id', 'Search By ID:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('id', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {!! Form::label('username', 'Search By Username:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {!! Form::submit('Find Comments', array('class' => 'btn btn-send ')) !!}
                </div>
                {!!Form::close()!!}

            </div>
@foreach($comment as $comments)
//data
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paginate` function immediately executes the query for you, so you are using [Collection functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) after that. The [`get`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-get) function on collections expects a key as a parameter, this is the problem.

To fix this, you can either remove the `->get()` or use the `paginate` function at the end of your query as shown below.

```
$comment = Comment::query();
$id = $request->input('id');
$name = $request->input('username');

if (!empty($id)) {
    $comment = $comment->where('id', $request->input('id'));
}

$result = $comment->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Ive tried this and it returns no results? seems like their is an issue with the Comment::query() not returning all?

Comment: The [`query()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query) function just creates a new query for a certain model. You probably will have to use the `paginate` function outside of the if structure, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since You have Paginated already

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();

    $id=$request->input('id');
    $name=$request->input('username');


    if(!empty($id)){
        $comment->where('id', $request->input('id') )->get();
    }
    if(!empty($name)){
        $comment->where($comment->author->username, 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
    }


    return view('comments.index')->withComment($comment->paginate(10));
}
```

You cannot paginate and get it again, its like using SELECT statement twice on same object.